# infinitesimal generators from infinitesimals [Xi]^1 , [Xi]^2 , [Phi]^1 using YaLie 2nd prolongation method

Tags: packages

How does one determine infinitesimal generators from infinitesimals [Xi]^1 , [Xi]^2 , [Phi]^1 using YaLie 2nd-prolongation method for a Diffusion PDE? Is there another YaLie package to use? Up to date I determined the general solutions of [Xi]^1 , [Xi]^2 , [Phi]^1 using YaLie 2nd prolongation method.

Comment: I am taking the unusual step of both upvoting and voting to close this. The upvote is so that you will have sufficient reputation to post comments. The closure is on grounds that this is too vague ("no code to replicate the problem" is the specific reason).